# What is the maximum possible bonus to Karma?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've been saving my [Jugs of Liquid Karma](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Jug_of_Liquid_Karma) from completing daily and monthly achievements, and I've got quite a few stashed away. Since it's possible to get bonuses to Karma through things like guild banners and some food types, I want to make sure that I get the most use out of them that I can.

**What is the maximum possible Karma bonus and what do I need to do to reach it?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**With regards to using Jugs/Flasks/Gulps/Drops of Karma most efficiently, the largest possible bonus at this time is 95%.**

To obtain this bonus, you'll need to:

- Use a [Karma Booster](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Karma_Booster) for 50%
- Touch a "+10% Karma and +10% Experience" Banner
- Eat an [ice cream food item](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bowl_of_Ice_Cream_Base#Recipes_requiring_Bowl_of_Ice_Cream_Base) for 5%
- Be under the effect of the "+15% Karma for 24 hrs" guild buff
- Have an item with a [Karmic Infusion](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Karmic_Infusion) in it equipped (15% bonus).

Altogether, these bonuses will combine additively to give a 95% bonus.

Additional Notes:

- 95% is not a fixed cap, it is simply the largest bonus available at this time. It is possible that more Karma Modifiers will be added at a later date.
- <strike>It's worth noting that although the [Outmanned](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Outmanned) buff claims to add an extra 33% to Karma gain, it does not work for liquid karma items (and as Raven Dreamer pointed out, it actually does not work at all right now).</strike> The [Outmanned](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Outmanned) buff no longer claims to add a Karma bonus (Thanks for pointing this out, Brian).
- Thanks to Metemer for pointing out that there is now a 10% Karma Banner.

Source: [Guild Wars 2 Wiki page on Karma Modifiers](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Karma#Karma_modifiers)

Comment: I'm not sure the largest possible bonus is 75% - the Outmanned buff doesn't work at all, so I wouldn't use that as proof that it caps at 75%.

Comment: @RavenDreamer The Outmanned buff shouldn't matter either way since it definitely doesn't affect liquid karma items, I only mentioned it for clarification. If it turns out that the wiki is wrong and the maximum is something other than 75%, I'll certainly accept an answer with the proper value.

Comment: That's what I mean, though -- the outmanned buff *doesn't* provide bonus karma (despite the tooltip) from *either* WvWvW events **or** liquid Karma. The so-called "cap" of 75% is simply the highest attainable karma increase. Before the Karma food came out, the "cap" was 70%. (And it turned out to not be one when the ice cream was released and folks confirmed 75%)

Comment: @RavenDreamer Ah, I understand. I wasn't meaning to suggest that there is a cap at all, but I see how you would think that from my wording. I was just interested in the maximum amount available *right now*, so that if I decided to use the items I would get the most out of them. I'll update my answer to be more clear.

Comment: So, instead of 4500 karma, it would give 7850, right?

Comment: @EduardoCopat 7875, I believe.

Comment: Update: for anyone wondering, the bonfire does not give +50% if you're already using a karma boost on the character. Vice versa.

Comment: Another update: Outmanned no longer claims to affect karma.

Answer (score 1):

As of the 2013.02.26 update, there is a banner that adds 10% karma bonus instead of the usual 5%. It doesn't stack with the 5% therefore the new maximum is 95% making a jug give 8775 karma instead of 4500 (4275 more).

Comment: This should either be a comment or an edit to Brysonic's answer.